# Cannot read property 'Constants' of underfind

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, reactjs, react-native

I have tried to integrates react-native with an existing android app.I followed [Official guide](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-android.html#content).When everything was done. I started the development server then run my android app.I got the following error.

In genymotion

[image]

In chrome console.

[image]

How to solve this problem.Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Would the fact that those components haven't loaded be anything to do with it? Probably.

Comment: @Andy Maps for android haven't been open sourced in the initial android release.http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/known-issues.html#views